# If Statement cant be recognised?

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with my if statement in my app development code

```
if (Intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

the error is brought up on the resolveActivity section which the error is as follows :

> Non-static method 
>   'resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)' cannot be referenced from a static context.

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: It means what it says -- you are in a static function when hitting this line (or called from one somewhere in the process chain), but you are calling a function that is not static (resolveActivity). You can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "resolveActivity" is non-static. You need an Intent-Instance to call that function.
If you are in an Activity you can use

```
if (getIntent().resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the Intent instead of referencing it directly from the class.
Like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
```

and then

```
if (myIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    {
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Basically, you try to get the method from the library class and you can get *mostly* only constants that way otherwise (in your case - methods) you need an object to which you *hang it* - so called dynamic reference.

Hope that helps!